# Can't copy .htpasswd or .changes from ubuntu server via samba. Why?

Tags: windows, ubuntu-10.04, twiki, .htpasswd

I'm trying to copy a twiki data dir (ubuntu server) via a samba share to an XP box... all files copy except for .htpasswd and .changes. Any ideas why not? Is there some service that is protecting them?

Comment: What command are you using to do the copy?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: drag n drop in windows, and also using Beyond Compare. Same problem with both: "access denied" I'm no pro at this, just muddling through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the file permissions are set such that the user you connect as via samba can not read them. `ls -l` at the Linux side will show you the ownership and rights information so you can see if there are differences between these files and the others, you may also see this in the Windows file properties dialogue (in the security tab) for each file depending on how your Samba daemon is configured.

Comment: ahh... -rw-------  all others are -rw-r--r--  does that mean i would need to alter the permissions for these two files before copying them?

Comment: Or change the group of the file to a group that the samba user is a member of. In either case take care especially if this is a shared server as the files may be read protected for a reason (the .htaccess may contain authentication settings for instance, in which case you wouldn't want to make it readable by all users).

Comment: I think this is the closest I'll get to fixing it tonight. Thanks David and the the other posters. I'll brush up on changing permissions tomorrow, I'm confident that will fix it. It's just a dev box, for practice so no worries. :-)

Comment: Thanks David, it was the permissions. I changed them to allow read access for all, copied, and then changed the permission's back.

Answer (score 0):

I copy these files off my server without any problems.

Permissions of these files might not be accessible by the samba server maybe?

Comment: I'm just doing a straight copy (drag n drop in windows), not changed any permissions. I stopped apache as I thought that might be preventing access to these files for some reason.